# How to package Python as RPM for install into /opt?

Tags: python, build, rpm

How to create a binary RPM package out of Python 2.7.2 sources for installation into a non-standard prefix such as /opt/python27?

Assume the following builds correctly.

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz
tar zxvf Python-2.7.2.tgz
cd Python-2.7.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/python27 --enable-shared
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Instead of the last command I'd like to build a binary RPM.

Comment: The objective here is to create a custom Python distribution that can be installed on another box, which satisfies dependencies on binary level but does not allow to build from sources (i.e. a production machine) and contains an older Python distro (i.e. 2.4.3 on RHEL5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPMs are built using [rpmbuild](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) from a .spec file. As an example, look at [python.spec](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=python.git;a=blob;f=python.spec;h=c098721755ad11681bb7d41568c6f9394c54a611;hb=HEAD) from Fedora.

If you don't need to build from sources then try rpm's --relocate switch on a pre-built RPM for your distribution:

```
rpm -i --relocate /usr=/opt/python27 python-2.7.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using RHEL5 and the Fedora spec file will likely contain dependencies, some of which would conflict with the system installed packages. See also my clarification comment above.

Comment: I was hoping for more detailed answer but since this was the only one hence will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bit late to respond now, but I was trying to do something similar and I didn't want to use --relocate because my package was not made to install anywhere except into /opt.

The way I did it was add the following two lines:

```
 Prefix: /opt
 %define _prefix /opt/
```

Don't forget that you also need to update your %files section to reflect that it is now installing in /opt